# How to host multiple Laravel sites/applications in a web root

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have 2 Laravel 4 applications.
I want one of them to be served from within a folder that is inside the other's root folder.

For example, let's say Application A is deployed to `/var/www/` folder, and I want Application B to be deployed to `/var/www/B/`.

When just naively putting it there, I get an error `NotFoundHttpException` from Application A's `RouteCollection.php`.

Any idea how this can be achieved?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you access you app using `/var/www/public/`  and `/var/www/b/public/` ?

Comment: @Junaid I can access application A from `/var/www/` folder, but not application B (which resides in `/var/www/B/`)

Answer (score 1):

I supose you're using apache2. There is a file in /etc his name is hosts, you can configure a virtual domain to access diferent directories like:

`127.0.0.1   project1.com
127.0.0.1   project2.com`

The you have to configure the virtualhost. You have to go to /etc/apache2/sites-avaible and copy the default config file 000-default.conf

`cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
 sudo cp 000-default.conf 001-laravel1.conf
 sudo nano 001-laravel1.conf`

Inside of the edit of the document you only have to change two things:

- ServerName (you have to put your virtual domain) -> project1.com
- DocumentRoot (you have to put your directory of your proyect) -> /var/www/A

And the last thing is create a symbolic link to this archive in the directory /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

`cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
ln -s 001-laravel1.conf ../sites-available/001-laravel1.conf`

Comment: @Gonazlo both apps are using the same domain/host, so I cannot differentiate them using domain names, or `ServerName` apache config property.

Comment: if there are two diferents aplications you can put the virtual domain like admin.laravel.com and customer.laravel.com But if you want the two app be one i supose you have to join and change the routing. I'm not sure,i don't know about laravel i thought your problem was with the apache :(

Comment: Thanks anyway for trying, @Gonzalo Muriel